# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

if execute the following code will show error message:

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment**

```
a = 220.0
b = 4300.0
c = 230.0/4300.0

def fun():
    while (c > a/b):
        a = a + 1
        print a/b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

but modify to :

```
a = 220.0
b = 4300.0
c = 230.0/4300.0

def fun():
    aa = a
    bb = b
    while (c > aa/bb):
        aa = aa + 1
        print aa/bb

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

it will fine.
Any advice or pointers would be awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now what did you want? Modify the global `a` or create a local `a` shadowing the global one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't modify a global variable without using the `global` statement:

```
def fun():
    global a 
    while (c > a/b):
        a = a + 1
        print a/b
```

As soon as python sees an assignment statement  like `a = a + 1` it thinks that the variable `a` is local variable and when the function is called the expression `c > a/b` is going to raise error because `a` is not defined yet.